# Создание процедур с временными таблицами

Tags: sql-server

Допустим, есть процедура, где используются временные таблицы. Так вот, если ошибиться в названии колонок при использовании временной таблицы при каком-нибудь соединении, то SQL SERVER это проглатывает.

Можно ли изменить поведение, что бы не ловить ошибки только при выполнении процедуры?

Answer (score 0):

В голову приходит только добавить проверку:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TempDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'Column' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '#TempTable%')
    PRINT 'Column exists'
ELSE
    PRINT 'Column doesn''t exists'
```

Comment: Не, я имел в виду, что бы при вызове CREATE PROCEDURE вылетала ошибка об отсутствии чего-либо.